# Subtract all values from data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Table data look like this

**id val**

1   4

2   2

3   1

I want result of subtract valu of val field in one sql statement.
like it should be like **4-2-1 = 1 if order by id asc, 1-2-4 = -5 if order by id desc**.

Comment: 4-2-1=1 - it is not equal to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable and increment it in the select statement:

```
declare @sum float

select @sum = case when @sum is null then value else @sum - value end
from YourTable
order by id

select @sum
```

To reverse the subtraction order, change `order by id` to `order by id desc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 1, 4
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 3, 1

SELECT  SUM(Val * CASE WHEN RowID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) RowID
            FROM    @Table
        ) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use just the sql without temp tables or variables:

select fromid.val - sumid.val

from (

select val

from t

where id = (

```
    select min(id)

    from t

  )
```

) fromid cross join (

```
select sum(val) as val

from t

where id > (

      select min(id)

      from t

    )
```

) sumid